# How to set up raid on a node in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a node pool in GKE where the node config specifies that each node has 2 local SSDs.  I want those two SSDs to appear as a single directory to my workload that's running on the node, and I'm thinking to achieve this I'd create a raid array from the two SSDs.

I'm not really sure how to do this?  I'm guessing that it happens at the node level, and not the pod level?

I'm not explicitly setting the image for the nodes, so they will be using cos.

Comment: This depends on the operating system. Linux has several packages supporting software RAID.

Comment: It's cos, I've edited the question to include the OS.  I'm more concerned with how I get a script running to configure each node, rather than the specifics about setting up the raid itself.  Because the node pool will dynamically scale, I don't know how to hook an init script into them.